# How to ignore Process.Start() "The system cannot find the file specified"?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm using this to run an external exe process:

```
using (Process p = new Process())
{
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "program.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "example";
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    string pResult = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.Close();
}
```

It works fine, but if the program.exe is moved or missing, the entire application crashes on p.Start();.

What is the best way to work around the crash even if program.exe is missing? 
I'd like the main application to keep running regardless if program.exe starts or not.

Should I use try/catch or is there a better way?

Comment: `File.Exists` ?

Comment: `File.Exists` *and* a `try/catch`

Comment: Forget about `File.Exists`. Use `try/catch` only: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer Exceptions are expensive and disrupt execution flow, if there is a common case where the file is not where you think I would *absolutely* use `File.Exsists` (and a try/catch just in case)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Don't use them for flow - use them for exceptional conditions. If the file is going to be missing more often than not, perhaps an altogether different approach should be considered.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer Maybe, but I wouldn't fault someone for doing a `File.Exists` check and then doing something like opening a file picker in the `else` clause. Seems perfectly normal to me. I think we basically agree here :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I agree to agree on this one :)

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer In this case I have a settings custom file browser and an environment variables checker to increase the chance the file is found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with any exception, use a `try/catch` block to avoid crashes.

That said, since you know the source of the problem is a missing file, just do an `if` check with `File.Exists`:

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{
   using (Process p = new Process)...
}
```

Probably wouldn't be a bad idea to use `try/catch` *anyways* to pick up any other exceptions.

Comment: Thanks I will try this. The program.exe will be wherever the user has it installed, but I think I have a way to detect or specify the location.

Answer (score 0):

This has been hashed out quite a bit in @BradleyDotNet's (correct) answer and the comments, but just to throw my two cents' worth in here, I think that you should use *only* `File.Exists(path)` for this. As other people have indicated, it's generally a bad idea (especially in .NET) to use exceptions and exception handling in place of control of flow with `if` statements.

One other guideline I'd like to point out here: only catch exceptions you know how to handle. You know how to handle the case where the file doesn't exist - just keep going as if nothing happened. In my mind, to justify having a try/catch block in addition to checking to see if the file exists, you'd have to list out what else could go wrong here (i.e. what things would result in an exception) and how you plan to handle it.